# Convert subset of rows to column pyspark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose we have the following df

```
Id PlaceCod  Val
1  1         0 
1  2         3
2  2         4 
2  1         5
3  1         6
```

How can I convert this DF to this one:

```
Id Store Warehouse
1  0     3
2  5     4
3  6     null
```

I've tried to use `df.pivot(f.col("PlaceCod"))` but got error message `'DataFrame has no pivot attribute'`

Comment: Where the `Store` and `Warehouse` came from?

Comment: try `df.groupBy('id').pivot('PlaceCod').count()`

Comment: @Emma when PlaceCod = 1 then is store, when PlaceCod = 2 then WareHouse

Comment: `pivot` is only available for GroupedData. try this way. `df.groupby('Id').pivot('PlaceCod').agg(F.first('Val'))`  Then you can rename the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted by @Emma on the comments:

```
df.groupby('Id').pivot('PlaceCod').agg(F.first('Val'))
```

Using the above solution my problem was solved!